# A function that deletes an instance by removing it from stage and nulling it does not remove it from memory

Tags: actionscript-3, events, event-listener

I have an issue with a function I use to delete an instance and replace it with another. Basically, it keeps the item in memory no matter what. Inside the object I have weak listeners and I null everything after it gets removed, but the function I run to check if it is still active tells me that it is (just an Event.ENTER_FRAME tracing some text, with a weak link).

Even when I removed everything from the instances I am loading, it still seems to stay in memory, according to my trace it still is. How do I completely delete something from memory more thoroughly than nulling it out after removing it from the stage? Am I not seeing something?

This is the function:

```
private function loadArea(inputArea:String)
            {                      
                    //This is for a checker to make sure that areas only get loaded once.
                    currentRoom = inputArea;

                    //If the area currently loaded is not null, make it null now.
                    if(selectedArea != null) selectedArea = null;

                    //Null any data inside of the reference used to create the name of the new area.
                    areaReference = null;
                    //Grab the class using the input.
                    areaReference = getDefinitionByName(inputArea + "Area") as Class;

                    //Null the sprite used to house the class
                    areaSprite = null;
                    //Set the holder as a new instance of the desired class.
                    areaSprite = new areaReference() as Sprite;

                    //If the selected area is still not null for some reason,
                    if(selectedArea != null)
                    {
                            //Remove the area from the container...
                            areaContainer.removeChild(selectedArea);
                            //...and nullify it.
                            selectedArea = null;
                    }

                    //Set the current area as the newly created instance.
                    selectedArea = areaSprite;

                    //If the area is not the "Game", load in the assets one way,                   
                    if(inputArea != "Game") selectedArea.construct(areaAssets);
                    //otherwise do it another way.
                    else selectedArea.construct(newScreenData,apiServer,cdnServer,areaAssets);

                    //This is for a checker that fades out the screen, which it needs to fade back in soon.
                    newScreenData = null;

                    //While the container for areas has any areas inside of it, remove them.
                    while(areaContainer.numChildren) areaContainer.removeChildAt(0);

                    //...then add the new instance area to the container.
                    areaContainer.addChild(selectedArea);

                    //...then let all the parts of the game know that a new area has been laoded in.
                    Global.echoEvent.echo("gameBootUp","playAreaIn");
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

The memory is actually released when Garbage Collector will find and erase an orphaned instance of yours. Before that, your memory usage will state there is an instance in memory. There is no way to force garbage collection, calling `System.gc()` only "instructs" Flash to run it, it might not obey. So, you have done what you had to, let it be.

Comment: `System.gc()` only works in debug mode anyway (unless this is an AIR app). Regardless, Garbage Collection is semi-intelligent. It won't remove any object from memory until it actually needs the memory that object occupies.

Answer (score 1):

Removing all references including stage and nulling an object is all it takes to free up memory.

If the object is not being released then you are missing something or doing something incorrectly or out of sequence.

Carefully go through your code, making sure you identify where objects are being referenced so you can remove them.

Looking at your example code:

```
if(selectedArea != null) selectedArea = null;
```

Here you are making sure that the selectedArea is null.
But immediately after you are testing selectedArea again
(you know it is null so this block is never used)

```
if(selectedArea != null){
//Remove the area from the container...
areaContainer.removeChild(selectedArea);
//...and nullify it.
selectedArea = null;
}
```

Comment: Does referencing anything global keep it in memory? I have a global variable I use to dispatch DataEvents to send strings. I add an event listener from inside the instance, so it can recieve events from other instances. I remove the listener though, so I'm not sure if maybe something else is going wrong revolving around global variables that maybe I don't know yet?

Answer (score 0):

In every language its VERY DIFFICULT to "clear" memory... even HTML.  That being said... try to reduce your memory footprint.

```
Correct Null:
1. remove all event listeners
2. remove all children
3. remove all mapped/referenced methods/parameters
4. set the class object to null
```

In most cases this is all you need to do, the WAY you do it will determine if the object gets cleared.  Consider the following situation.

You have a custom sprite class (MEMORY FOOTPRINT #1) that has a mapped property (mapping happen when one class object references another).  Once you map/reference one object to another = MEMORY FOOTPRINT #2.  Adding events = MEMORY FOOTPRINT #3, etc and so on.

Custom Sprite

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

class CustomSprite extends Sprite{

    private var _mappedProperty:Object;

    public function addMapping(map:Object):void{
        _mappedProperty = map;
    }

    public function finalize():void{
        _mappedProperty = null;
    }
}
```

Assuming we're using CustomSprite in many other methods, lets look at some common ways of removing the ojbect.

**INCORRECT** - in this situation [objToRemove] was not set to null to free its memory:

```
var objToRemove:CustomSprite = new CustomSprite;

function doSomething(referenceObj:CustomSprite):void{

    var methodObj:CustomSprite = referenceObj;

    //CRAZY LINES OF CODE

    methodObj = null;       //frees memory from [doSomething::methodObj]
    referenceObj = null;    //frees memory from [doSomething::referenceObj]

    //objToRemove is not cleared and will remain in memory
}
```

**INCORRECT** - in this situation [objToRemove] has a reference object so it will not clean until the reference is removed:

```
var objToRemove:CustomSprite = new CustomSprite;
var mappedObject:Sprite = new Sprite;

objToRemove.addMapping(mappedObject);       
objToRemove.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);

//CRAZY LINES OF CODE

//remove all children
while(objToRemove.numChildren > 0){
    objToRemove.removeChildAt(0);
}

//remove all event listeners
objToRemove.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrame);

//this will NOT work
objToRemove = null;

//reason is objToRemove has a reference object of [mappedObject]
//[mappedObject] is not a child so it needs to be removed manually
//from WHITIN the CustomSprite class using [CustomSprite::finalize()]
```

Ok... breath... the correct way is actually simple.

**CORRECT** - here we are using [Dynamic] objects rather than [Static] class objects, this is considered Object Mapping:

```
//think of this as a global list of objects
var objPool:Dictionary = new Dictionary;

//create a pool reference
objPool['poolObj'] = new CustomSprite;

//CRAZY LINES OF CODE;

//do the normal [null] process

//both of these will work
objPool['poolObj'] = null;
//or
delete objPool['poolObj'];
```

**SUPER ADVANCED CORRECT** - no example provided, I have to get back to work lol...

```
1. Take a ByteArray clone of the class
2. User a Loader to construct the ByteArray as the class, rather than using "new"
3. When finished... unload/remove the loader
4. EVERYTHING will clear... thats how a Loader works! 
(Not getting into why and how... too long of an explanation)
```

Although this works flawlessly... its not generally accepted or suggested in a work environment.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I never knew how to properly clean up after my code. I'll have to try out the last suggestion there in an experiment to fully understand it, but I would love to be free in knowing that it's all gone when I want it to be. Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: No problem... the super advanced solution is after many years of working with Flash.  There are a few other ways to do what was mentioned but these should give you a good start.